# Docker network without IP address on host

Tags: linux-networking, docker, bridge

I'm trying to create a Docker network which would use an existing bridge on the host but without configuring any IP on this bridge. When I run:

```
docker network create -o "com.docker.network.bridge.name=br0" testnet
```

Docker automatically assign an IP address on the host and always use this IP as the gateway for other containers.

What I want is a network without an IP on the host and to use another container as the gateway (this container is connected to multiple networks). I have very good reasons for this setup and not letting the host directly route between these networks. Is it possible and how can I achieve that?

Thank you in advance for your help,

spongebob

Comment: Did you try `docker network create --internal ...`

Comment: Yes, the only difference `--internal` makes is that it adds some iptables rules so containers cannot communicate with other networks. But it still adds an IP address on the host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the source code it does not seem possible to do that with the `bridge` network driver. The [createNetwork](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/899426a76286eb75153f4e53015d614717a1ec8e/components/engine/vendor/github.com/docker/libnetwork/drivers/bridge/bridge.go#L617) function always tries to [setup an IPv4 even if the bridge already exists](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/899426a76286eb75153f4e53015d614717a1ec8e/components/engine/vendor/github.com/docker/libnetwork/drivers/bridge/bridge.go#L714). The [setupBridgeIPv4](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/899426a76286eb75153f4e53015d614717a1ec8e/components/engine/vendor/github.com/docker/libnetwork/drivers/bridge/setup_ipv4.go#L29) function sets up an IPv4 on the bridge and defines this IP as the gateway for the network.

I solved my problem by using the `none` network driver and using [pipework](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework) to manually attach the containers to my host bridge. The disadvantage of this solution is that containers must be re-attached to the bridges each time they are restarted but that can be automated with a systemd service starting after the docker one.